# How to add a condition in Numpy 2D random list

Tags: python, numpy

i need to create a set of 100 random 2D points with two requirements.
A: the points must be inside a rectangle with specific dimensions.
B: the points must satisfy a condition; for example, given the coordinates x and y of a certain generated point, x+y<2.

I'm able to generate a set of points inside a rectangle:

```
xyMin = [xMin, yMin]
xyMax = [xMax, yMax]

data = np.random.uniform(low=xyMin, high=xyMax, size=(100,2))
```

How can i add the second condition? I could use a while loop, generating one point per loop and checking the condition. If the condition is satisfied, increase the counter and go to the next point until the index is equal to 100. If not, try again in the next loop without increase the index.

Is it possible to achieve the same result using list comprehension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a faster way than generating pairs one at a time. It just re-generates all pairs which fail the second condition until there are no failures left.

```
xyMin = 1.1
xyMax = 0.9
data = np.random.uniform(low=xyMin, high=xyMax, size=(100,2))
while True:
    failures = data.sum(axis=1)>=2
    n = failures.sum()
    if n>0:
        data[failures] = np.random.uniform(low=xyMin, high=xyMax, size=(n,2))
    else:
        break
```

That said, study this [question from stackexchange mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18686/uniform-random-point-in-triangle). There's going to be a much better way. You can generate points in the triangle `x+y<2` like this:

```
A = np.array([0,0])
B = np.array([2,0])
C = np.array([0,2])
r1,r2 = np.random.random(size=(2,100,1))
points = (1-np.sqrt(r1))*A + (np.sqrt(r1)*(1-r2))*B + r2*np.sqrt(r1)*C
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample answer using some guess values

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xyMin = [0, 0]
xyMax = [3, 3]

data = np.random.uniform(low=xyMin, high=xyMax, size=(10000,2))
mask = (np.sum(data, axis=1)<2)
data = data[mask]
plt.scatter(data[:, 0], data[:,1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: this is not what OP wants, since by 'masking' the original set you remove values that do not fit the criteria, therefore trimming the number of datapoints away from the desired 10,000

Comment: Thank you! Even if it's not the correct answer, i'll keep it for the future, the mask function is very interesting.